# c# draw the z axis

Tags: c#, coordinates

I'm drawing coordinate axes in picturebox

```
    void draw_cor()
    {
        int w = pictureBox1.ClientSize.Width / 2;
        int h = pictureBox1.ClientSize.Height / 2;
        Refresh();
        Graphics e = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
        e.TranslateTransform(w, h);
        DrawXAxis(new Point(-w, 0), new Point(w, 0), e);
        DrawYAxis(new Point(0, h), new Point(0, -h), e);
        DrawZAxis(new Point(-pictureBox1.ClientSize.Width , pictureBox1.ClientSize.Height), new Point(pictureBox1.ClientSize.Width, -pictureBox1.ClientSize.Height ), e);

    }
```

markup and text for the x axis as an example

```
    private void DrawXAxis(Point start, Point end, Graphics g)
    {
        for (int i = Step; i < end.X; i += Step)
        {
            g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, i, -5, i, 5);
            DrawText(new Point(i, 5), (i / Step).ToString(), g, false);
        }

        for (int i = -Step; i > start.X; i -= Step)
        {
            g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, i, -5, i, 5);
            DrawText(new Point(i, 5), (i / Step).ToString(), g, false);
        }
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, start, end);
        g.DrawString("X", new Font(Font.FontFamily, 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(end.X - 15, end.Y));

    }

    private void DrawText(Point point, string text, Graphics g, bool isYAxis)
    {
        var f = new Font(Font.FontFamily, 6);
        var size = g.MeasureString(text, f);
        var pt = isYAxis
            ? new PointF(point.X + 1, point.Y - size.Height / 2)
            : new PointF(point.X - size.Width / 2, point.Y + 1);
        var rect = new RectangleF(pt, size);
        g.DrawString(text, f, Brushes.Black, rect);
    }
```

can someone explain how to make a method for marking the z axis?
I understand that the shift should be diagonal in both x and y, but nothing worked out for me and no markup appears on the screen.(so far I have managed to draw only a straight line diagonally )

upd:

```
    private void DrawZAxis(Point start, Point end, Graphics g)
    {
        

        for (int i = -Step, j=Step ; i > start.X; i -= Step,j += Step)
        {
            g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, new Point(i-5, j), new Point(i+5, j));
           
            DrawText(new Point(i, j), (i / -Step).ToString(), g, false);
        }
...
}
```

I seem to have succeeded, but I ran into such a problem:

[image]

[image]

that is, the markup is not always on the coordinate axis. How to avoid this? It is necessary that the numbers are always on the axis (I suppose I should calculate the coefficient when the window is scaled, but only where to add it or by what to multiply?)

Comment: "but nothing worked out for me" - show us what you tried so that we can help fix the code.

Comment: This seems to be a mathematics question. You're essentially asking how to project 3 dimensions onto a 2d plane. In graphics programming, matrices are normally used for this.

Comment: @Enigmativity I updated the question and added the code. (now something appears, but not on the axis..)

Comment: why not just use a rotate transform and use the same X axis code to generate the Z then rotate back?

Answer (score 2):

You are dealing with 3D data, so you should use 3D tools to transform your axes, and your data for that matter.

So you need to define a projection from 3D space to 2D space. This is usually done by defining a projection matrix. There are multiple [projections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#Oblique_projection) to chose from, it looks like your projection is Oblique, but orthographic and perspective projections are also common. The System.Numerics.Vectors library has classes for [Matrix4x4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.matrix4x4?view=net-6.0), vector2/3/4, with methods to create your projection and transform your vectors.

After transforming a vector you can simply keep the x/y values and discard the z-value to get your image coordinates. Note that if using a [perspective transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Perspective_projection) you need a vector4 and divide the x/y/z elements by W.

Armed with these tools it should be a fairly simple thing to generate start/end points for each axis, and create tick-marks in 3D, before projecting everything to 2D for drawing.

Another option would be to just do everything in [Wpf3D](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/3-d-graphics-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) to start with, this will likely make some functionality like rotating the camera simpler.